# How to I set the location folder of Control Panel resources?

Tags: control-panel, cache, cli, resources

I'm trying to use the `./craft clear-caches/all` CLI command.

Everything is working fine, except that I always get this error:

> Error clearing cache Control Panel resources: Unable to clear Control
>   Panel resources because the location isn't known for console commands.

How can I set this resources folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you **@Brandon Kelly** for the solution:

> That’s because `@webroot` is only reliable on web requests. To fix,
>   update your `resourceBasePath` config setting to a real path:
>
> `'resourceBasePath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/web/cpresources'`